How to address the leakage from the back of newly installed stone sink?
Background-Kitchen renovation in brick and mortar building.
Location-West Bengal, India.
Issue-after installation of stone/marble sink, there is leakage from the back;
Two installers had tried caulking and epoxy+hardening. It still leaks when the water reaches to 4-6 inches.
Question:

Will I have to redo the whole countertop?
Should I instead install a readymade sink?
What installation type would be best(undermount/drop-in/etc)?






Wow that looks terrible.

I'm surprised it doesn't leak way before 4 to 6 inches. I'd be cleaning that whole mess up, scrape all the caulk, epoxy up from the bottom and corners, redo the drain and then and only then, re caulk all the seams.
If you don't want to go through all that, get a custom made drop in sink that will sit on the lip of the counter top and seal it well. You might have to cut away a bit of the corner in the upper left of the opening to get over the lip.
